# fulCalendar 4 / superagent: how to send http-headers

Tags: http-headers, fullcalendar, jwt, superagent

I'm using the latest version of fullcalender 4 in an angular 7 project. Fullcalendar 3 used ajax to request json feeds for the events, but version 4 relies on SuperAgent, so a lot of commands were renamed or removed. One of them being "headers: {}". Since its not a public Calendar, i need to send a jwt token, but i cant find a smart way to do that, besides adding it to the request url. Is the headers feature just renamed and i dont find the docs to use it, especially since SuperAgent makes sending headers super easy, or is it not supported (yet)?

Comment: I found this relating to superagent: https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#setting-header-fields. Seems it's pretty easy to set your headers via that. It's unclear how this relates to fullCalendar exactly? Can you be more specific about what feature of fullCalendar you're trying to use and how that ties in with setting ajax headers in super-agent?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Fullcalendar (4+) uses SuperAgent to request json feeds for the displayed events. These are defined within the Options object of the Calendar, e.g. { events: { url: '/feed.php' } }. The older versions of fullcalendar used jquery's ajax functionality for the same requests, which allowed to add custom headers just by extending the events obj like this: events: { url: '/feed.php' , headers: { foo: 'bar' } }. This scenario is perfectly documented in SuperAgent, but since im usings fullcalenders built in Options i cant use SuperAgent directly.

Comment: Version 3 of FullCalendar didnt have the headers options in its own documentation, so i'm hoping the fact that v4 didnt put it in either doesnt mean it doesn't work.

Comment: ah I see. v3 didn't have headers explicitly in the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) no, but it does mention that "You can also specify any of the jQuery $.ajax options within the same object", thus implying that it is available. An equivalent statement is missing from the [v4 docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-json-feed) so if I had to guess I'd say it wouldn't work, but I haven't tried it. Since in super-agent the setting is done via a method instead of an option, it's probably harder to incorporate.

Comment: You might find you have to use the [events-as-a-function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-function) setup instead, so that you can write your own totally custom ajax call to retrieve events, thus allowing you to include the header that way instead. But then again since v4 is still not released yet, you could perhaps ask the fullCalendar maintainer for a feature request to see if what you're looking for can be included in a final version, or a future version. I think you can make feature requests via the fullCalendar GitHub page.